# Python with selenium webscraping unable to find elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to write a webscraping in python that will activate the "onclick" functionality of certain buttons on a webpage because the tables with the data I want are converted to csv, which makes it much easier to access. But the problem is that I am unable to locate elements by xpath at all when using PhantomJs. How can I click the element and access the csv content that I want?

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

url = "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609180nwe.htm"
xpath = "//*[@id='all_player_offense']/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[3]/button"

path_to_phantomjs = 'browser/phantomjs'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = path_to_phantomjs)
browser.get(url)

delay=3
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'all_player_offense'))
WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(element_present)

browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

And I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//*[@id='all_player_offense']/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[3]/button'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"153","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:50989","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"sessionId\": \"93ff24f0-9cbe-11e6-8711-bdfa3ff9cfb1\", \"value\": \"//*[@id='all_player_offense']/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[3]/button\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/93ff24f0-9cbe-11e6-8711-bdfa3ff9cfb1/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Comment: Have you verified you have the correct `xpath`? I've tried the same code in the ChromeDriver and I'm getting the same error message.

Comment: It should also be noted that the element you're trying to get to is only accessible after having the cursor *hover* over the main menu that contains it.

Answer (score 1):

> **IMPORTANT THING I FORGOT TO MENTION:** As described in this [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11637), try putting `set_window_size(width, height)` or `maximize_window()`after setting the webdriver. You should also consider telling the webdriver to `implicitly_wait(10)` for the element to appear.

So there's a special maneuver you have to perform in order for the Selenium Webdriver to properly emulate what you're doing. In essence, to get the desired data, you'd have to:

**A**: *Hover* over the "Share & More" dropdown menu. Then

**B**: *Click* "Get table as CSV (Excel)".

For **A**, this involves having to place the emulated cursor on the element without clicking it. This idea of "mouse over" can be done with the `move_to_element()` function provided in the `ActionChains` class. So at the top you'd insert this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

You want Selenium to find the specific element and move to it. You can achieve this with 2 lines of code:

```
dropdown = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="all_player_offense"]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]')
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(dropdown).perform()
```

If you omit the above, you'll get an `ElementNotVisibleException`.

Now for **B**, you should be able to do `browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()`.

Comment: Just to emphasize, this works with only **Firefox** or **Chrome**, I've tried everything and still cannot get it to work on PhantomJS, but hopefully I've led you to the right direction!